# Parse each word and not a string pattern

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm coding a discord.js bot to prevent from displaying message with banned words into. I have an array containing all the banned words and I'm checking if the message contain one of them with `.includes` method.

My issue is that this method parse the whole string pattern so let's say **"apple"** word is banned, if you send a message saying **"Im eating a pineapple"** your message will be banned because it contains **"apple"** somewhere in the string regardless the rest. What I want to do is check each word in isolation, not if the string contains the patern, so **"Im eating an apple"** should be banned for exemple and not **"Im eating a pineapple"**.

I tried to add blank spaces before and after each word in my array like `" apple "` but it doesn't work cause it will say the word is fine if you don't put the spaces in the message. I had another idea which was to add in my condition something to check if characters before and after the word are spaces or null like `&& word+1 = " " && word-1 = " "` but idk if it's doable. Here is a sample of my code :

```js
const bannedWords = [                //banned words list
  "apple",
  "car",
  "test"
  ];

var word2parse = document.getElementById("word2parse");
var output = document.getElementById("display");

function parse(){

  if (bannedWords.some(word => word2parse.value.includes(word))){    //if message contain one  
  output.innerHTML = "this word is banned";                          //of the word in the array
  }
  else{
  output.innerHTML = "this word is fine";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" id = "word2parse">
<input type = "button" onclick = "parse()" value = "Parse">
<p id = "display"></p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression for that with word boundaries (`\b`):

```js
const bannedWords = [                //banned words list
  "apple",
  "car",
  "test"
];
const bannedRegex = RegExp("\\b(" + bannedWords.join("|") + ")\\b");

var word2parse = document.getElementById("word2parse");
var output = document.getElementById("display");

function parse() {
  if (bannedRegex.test(word2parse.value)) {
    output.innerHTML = "this text contains a banned word";
  } else{
    output.innerHTML = "this text is fine";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type = "text" id = "word2parse">
<input type = "button" onclick = "parse()" value = "Parse">
<p id = "display"></p>
```

Comment: Using any of the `bannedWords` as value, the parse result is different every time... Not sure why... But each click get an opposite result.

Comment: ty for your answer, yea `car` provide opposite value each click and same for all words, I implemented your code in my discord.js and its doing same, 1/2 times word isnt banned

Comment: Fixed now, it was a behaviour caused by the g-flag (removed). (Details: regular expression objects maintain state in JavaScript, so that if you perform one test, it remembers where it stopped so a next test will continue from that point. That is undesired behaviour here).

Comment: Ty, can you explain me really quick what `join("|")` do ?

Comment: `join("|")` concatenates all words into one string, and uses that pipe symbol as separator. In regular expressions it has the meaning of "OR".

Answer (score 1):

I think Regexp with word boundary would help here. That \b below excludes pineapple from serach.

```
[...'apple pineapple'.matchAll(/apple/g)].length
2
[...'apple pineapple'.matchAll(/\bapple/g)].length
1
```

Comment: ty for your answer, is there a way to exclude all word of an array ?

Comment: @trincot got that right in answer above but if you want to combine these two (and count matches in the same time)

const bannedWords = [                //banned words list
  "apple",
  "car",
  "test"
];
const bannedRegex = RegExp("\\b(" + bannedWords.join("|") + ")\\b", 'g');
[...'apple pineapple car carapace'.matchAll(bannedRegex)].length